# How to configure buildbot slave to run from behind a firewall?

Tags: buildbot

Is it possible to run a buildbot-slave from inside a corporate firewall where you are allowed to create only outgoing connection on standard HTTP(s) ports?

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

In this case you should run your master to use exactly these ports, i.e. running web interface on HTTP(80) port while using HTTPS(443) port for slaves' connections. However this would require master to run with root privileges which is bad. In this case you could redirect traffic from these ports to the actual used in master with iptables. With default master ports for web interface(8010) and slave connections(9989) you'll get something like:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9989
```

The same goes for web interface in case you're not using any proxy HTTP server (like nginx, haproxy, lighthttpd, etc).

Comment: Of course, this only works if the firewall is filtering just based on ports. There is no way to run a slave over an HTTP connection.